# Passing data to the next POST request from that was fetched in the previous one [Swift / SwiftUI]

Tags: json, swift, post

I am looking for a way how to pass further data that was received in the previous `POST` request. Below is my code. 
Actual result: `authtoken` and `sms_id` become an empty `String`.
Some clarifications: The second `POST` request is called in the next screen in the sequence when the first is completed. TIA.

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

enum APIError: Error {
 case responseProblem
 case decodingProblem
 case encodingProblem
}

class NetworkService: ObservableObject {

@Published var user: UserRegisterRequest?
@Published var userRegistered: UserRegistered?

let uuid = UIDevice.current.identifierForVendor?.uuidString
let appid = "com.website.me"
var authToken = ""
var sms_id = ""

func postPhoneValidation(_ phone: String, completion: @escaping (Result<UserRegisterRequest, APIError>) -> Void) {

    do {
        guard let url = URL(string: APIRequests.postPhoneValidation) else { fatalError() }

        let body: [String: Any] = ["phone" : phone]

        let finalBody = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: body)

        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.httpBody = finalBody

        request.setValue(uuid, forHTTPHeaderField: "X-AUTH-Device")
        request.setValue(appid, forHTTPHeaderField: "X-AUTH-AppID")

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, _ in

            guard let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpResponse.statusCode == 200,

                let jsondata = data else {

                completion(.failure(.responseProblem))
                return
            }

            do {
                let validatedPhoneDictionary = try JSONDecoder().decode(UserRegisterRequest.self, from: jsondata)

                self.authToken = validatedPhoneDictionary.auth_token

                self.sms_id = validatedPhoneDictionary.sms_id

                completion(.success(validatedPhoneDictionary))

                print(validatedPhoneDictionary)



            } catch {
                completion(.failure(.decodingProblem))
            }

        }
        .resume()

    } catch {
        completion(.failure(.encodingProblem))
    }
}

func postSignUp(_ otpSms: String, completion: @escaping (Result<UserRegistered, APIError>) -> Void) {
    do {
        guard let url = URL(string: APIRequests.postSignUp) else { fatalError() }

        let body : [String: Any] = ["otpSms" : otpSms, "sms_id" : self.sms_id]


        let finalBody = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: body)

        var request = URLRequest(url: url)


        request.httpMethod = "POST"

        request.httpBody = finalBody

        request.setValue(uuid, forHTTPHeaderField: "X-AUTH-Device")
        request.setValue(appid, forHTTPHeaderField: "X-AUTH-AppID")
        request.setValue(self.authToken, forHTTPHeaderField: "X-AUTH-Token")


        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, _ in

            guard let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpResponse.statusCode == 200,

                let jsondata = data else {

                completion(.failure(.responseProblem))
                return
            }

            do {
                let registeredUser = try JSONDecoder().decode(UserRegistered.self, from: jsondata)

                completion(.success(registeredUser))

                print(registeredUser)



            } catch {
                completion(.failure(.decodingProblem))
            }

        }
        .resume()
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You have showed the methods you wrote, but you never show how you are calling them.

Comment: @creeperspeak, hi! Thank you for your comment. It led me to check again my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for my problem was the moment that in view where I call the second method I've created a new instance of NetworkService instead of access it as ObservedObject. When I've changed it the problem was solved. –